# algolia WP => We're experiencing processing delay: last query analyzed 286 hours ago

Tags: algolia

Here is what I got on my "analytics" panel on algolia " We're experiencing processing delay: last query analyzed 286 hours ago." so it's pretty much 11 days late, just when I setup algolia for WP.

Is someone else having the same problem ?

I use ithemes security, all other plugins are really common and standard.
Is it possible that the security plugin blocks something that the algolia plugin needs to transmit the analytics ?

Because for front user, everything is fine and working. I just go to analytics.

Even if someone has a good tut on deploying algolia on WP, I'll take it. Because I still like this service for now.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first error related to analytics, it is not related to the WordPress plugin, but simply alerting you that the Analytics stats are not up to date yet. This should eventually resolve by itself.

For installing the Search by Algolia for WordPress plugin, best resource for now is the official documentation available here: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/configuration.html

Let us know if that helped,